# Need you inputs with dealing location transfer

Tags: software-industry, management, human-resources

I am currently working as a individual contributor with IT Product based MNC and i have been star performer through out my 4 years of exp with this firm. i & my wife work for different organizations in different cities. Myself in Noida whereas my wife works in Pune. I basically wanted to settle down in Pune because i have all my facilities like Home, parents & in laws to take care of my baby.

I had requested my manager to pitch my transfer to Pune since i have a facility in Pune and can manage things from that location. I tried convincing my manager that what benefits i get by working from Pune location as well to firm but they think otherwise like what if i quit and move to different organization or how can he give answer to another employees who wants to work from different organization. HR policies is quiet lean and depends on manager or director opinion.

so, i need inputs to put my best thought forward so that they will not have any second opinion and have trust on me by working from other location. Please help me with your suggestions.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Can you clear up the question?

Comment: Need suggestion  to counter my manager opinion that other employees will request transfer to another location.

Comment: Your manager is probably right, other employees will likely request transfer if they see you do it.  Your job is to educate your manager as to why that is a good thing, not bad.

Comment: To put it another way, why should he do it for you if he won't do it for anyone else.

Answer (score 3):

You've tried to convince your manager with how moving would benefit you.  You need to have reasons for how it would benefit him and the company.  If you can prove a benefit to the company if you were to move, then he will be more interested in listening to you.  How it benefits you is completely immaterial.

If there are no benefits for them if you move, why should they even consider it?